# Enumerables in Powershell versus pipes

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am so confused. I can't understand why a foreach in Powershell behaves so differently than C#.

This simple code produces no output:

```
@{a=1; b=2} | %{ $_.key }
```

An approximation of this I did in Linqpad using C# gives the output I'd expect:

```
var ht = new Hashtable();
ht["a"] = 1;
ht["b"] = 2;

foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in ht)
{
    kvp.Key.Dump();
}

// output

a
b
```

If I enumerate the Keys member of the hashtable, I can do what I need. But I don't understand why enumerating the hashtable itself doesn't return the key-value pairs. In fact it seems to return the object itself:

```
>     @{a=1; b=2} | %{ $_.gettype() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

What's Powershell doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerShell pipeline will "unroll" arrays and collections (one level), but not hash tables.  If you want to enumerate the key-value pairs of a hashtable in PowerShell, call the .getenumerator() method:

```
$ht = @{a=1;b=2}
$ht.GetEnumerator()



Name                           Value                                                             
----                           -----                                                             
a                              1                                                                 
b                              2
```

Comment: Yay, that's what I needed, thanks! Btw how do you know this? Is there a doc that explains the unrolling? I didn't even think to use this keyword in my searches, though now that I know it I see many hits.

Comment: I don't remember where I first learned this, or if it was by discovery, but you can easily verify it yourself.  Build a 2D array, and send it through the pipeline to foreach-object. Each object will be one of the second-level arrays.

Comment: Indeed, if you want to prevent the pipeline unrolling arrays you need to pass the with a comma prefix like: ,@(1,2,3) Which then passes the entire array instance as a single pipeline object instead of iterating over the contents. (Personally I find the unrolling  extremely annoying, and it seems to always be the opposite of what I wanted, but who knows, maybe i'm just not taking advantage of that functionality optimally)